# How to Track a page within a existing profile?

Tags: google-analytics, reporting

I manage a site and do mailing per month.

I'm tracking - `www.example.com`  but, I put my mailings under

- `www.example.com/news/newyear/`
- `www.example.com/news/sales/`
- `www.example.com/news/promo1/`
- etc.

Instead of creating new profiles for each mailing, is it possible create sub profiles and track them as selecting profile from Google Analytics.

I hope - I described my question. :)

regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under Google Analytics, I believe what you want are [Advanced Segments](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=108040).

So for your example, you would create 3 of these, here's an example:

1. Go to *My Customizations > Advanced Segments*
2. Click *+ Create new custom segment*
3. Drag over "*Dimensions > Content > Page*"
4. Choose "*Matches exactly*" and enter "/newyear/"
5. Enter a name for this, save the Advanced Segment.